# Thinkpad E14 gen. 2 AMD display freeze

Tags: hardware, manjaro, laptop, freeze, thinkpad

After being able to circumvent the fn-keys issue with my Thinkpad E14 (AMD)

an annoying defect came up. Sometimes the randomly freezes at an irregular interval and you have to hard shut down the laptop by long-pressing the shutdown button. Music playback continues but the display only shows a frozen picture. The keyboard input does not seem to continue working. Lately, it happens about once or twice a day.

Has anyone who owns a Thinkpad E14 / E15 experienced this?
Any hints to get more detailed information about this issue using logs, … are greatly appreciated. (I used `journalctl` but did not find anything special.

Currently, I am running Manjaro with Kernel `5.9.11-3-MANJARO`.

Comment: Are you running the latest updated BIOS? You can download the bootable bios update cd from lenovo

Comment: @GMaster I upgraded it once from 1.04 to 1.08 without any effect. Now updated it to the newest version 1.09.

Comment: Ubuntu, kernel 5.8.0-48-generic - no freezes, works fine, but Ubuntu 20.04 (don't remember the kernel) was horrible, but still, no freezes. Maybe you should try some USB-live systems.

Comment: Luckily for me the issue is (at least until now) is no longer present since ca. a month, so I hope it doesn't come back anymore (Kernel 5.11.6)

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Linux without (serious) issues on this laptop. I don't see the screen freeze issue you're discussing. The two workarounds which might be worth trying for you are:

1. Install kernel version 5.8.10 or 5.11.0 (other earlier kernels and some in between had issues; these are the ones that I've tried which I know work).
2. Run a suspend once per boot with (can add into crontab with @reboot for timing)

   ```
   sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 2
   ```

   (You may already be doing this as it's the workaround for the function key issue you mentioned.)

I also disable the wifi's power saving mode to keep it stable after waking from sleep, but that's probably not related to this issue.

I made [full notes](https://rd.nz/2020/10/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-the-lenovo-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-amd) if you want to try following what I did.

Comment: Thanks for full notes, very helpful.  Do you really think the "Windows Prep" section is required?  I'm thinking of buying this laptop but without Windows on it.

Comment: Sure I'd buy it without Windows if that was an option!